# space proportional between points in x-axis

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible in high-charts to show your X axis proportional to your data points.
Lets say my x axis data is [1,2,5,8,30,50] and these are say years.
I would like the chart to distance the points proportionally so the chart looks more reasonable to view. In this example while point 1, 2 would be closer but distance between 2 and 5 should be roughly three times distance between 1 and 2 and so on.
Basic idea is when you see how the values are changing between year 8 and 30 than visually it conveys right message to your brain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tickPositions` feature and pass a wanted array of the xAxis values to achieve your requirements.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vm1eh4su/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful to explore the api more but i need to provide a label at each tick-position. For example, i would like 1 to appear as 'One' on x axis and so on. Please let me know if there is a way.

Comment: @Mark1234 I think that you should be able to achieve it by using the `xAxis.labels.formatter` callback: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter